# Converting $antilog$ into exponential form

Tags: logarithms

$$log_a (x) = y$$

$$\Rightarrow x = a^{y}$$

Similarly, if 
$$antilog_a (y) = x$$ How will it be written in exponential form?

Comment: If $x=a^y$, and $x=\operatorname{antilog}_a(y)$, then by transitivity...

Comment: See here: http://www.mathcaptain.com/algebra/inverse-logarithm.html

Comment: anti$\log_a y = a^y$

Answer (score 3):

By definition, the anti-log is the inverse of the log:

$$\operatorname{antilog}_a(y)=x$$

Take the log of both sides:

$$\log_a(\operatorname{antilog}_a(y))=\log_a(x)$$

They cancel, and we are left with

$$y=\log_a(x)$$

Comment: Same thinking I was just typing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the anti-log is the inverse of the log: $${antilog}_a(y)=x$$ Taking log both the sides: $$\log_a(x)=\log_a({antilog}_a(y))$$ The $\log$ and $anti\log$ will cross each other $$y=\log_a(x)$$ Hence, $$a^y=x$$

Answer (score -1):

If $$antilog_a(y) = x $$
$$\Rightarrow a^{y} = x $$

**credit**: *John* & *J. M* from the comments

Comment: But you used the answer by the "Simple Art" and "Harsh Kumar"